# Camel - Using property in Spring DSL

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to set some properties in my process method but I'm not able to figure out that how to use those properties in xml, like I can use header values in xml easily by using syntax : ${in.header.myKey}

Here's my code :

```
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:start.queue" />
            <to uri="stream:out" />
            <process ref="jsonProcessor"></process>
             <to uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation(${in.property.SourceMap}, ${in.property.DestinationMap})" />
    </route>
```

Here in.property.SourceMap is Unknown function. What is the correct way?
Would be great if it is something similar to header. Also I want to use property only and not header since values of header may not persists later in my routes.

Here's process method code:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, String>> body = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
    Map<String, String> sourceMap = body.get(0);
    Map<String, String> destinationMap = body.get(1);
    exchange.setProperty("SourceMap", sourceMap);
    exchange.setProperty("DestinationMap", destinationMap);

}
```

Kindly provide the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hit and trial I got the working solution:

```
<route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:start.queue" />
            <to uri="stream:out" />
            <process ref="jsonProcessor"></process>
             <to uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation(${property.SourceMap}, ${property.DestinationMap})" />
    </route>
```

Answer (score 6):

There could be multiple solution combinations for your problem.

Sample Property Key and Value.

```
<cm:property name="app.user" value="PROD008"/>
```

In Route if u want to set header with property value. Use below code snippet.

```
<setHeader headerName="password">
    <simple>${properties:app.user}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

If you want to use property, you can use below snippet.

```
<to uri="{{some.endpoint}}"/>
```

For your example: if Properties are SourceMap and DestinationMap you can use any of below.

```
1. <to uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation(${property.SourceMap}, ${property.DestinationMap})" />

2. <to uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation({{SourceMap}},{{DestinationMap}})" />
```

If you want to use header instead of property then use below code snippet.

```
<to uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation(${header.SourceMap}, ${header.DestinationMap})" />
```